# Want to show each fragment below the buttons respectively only when button get clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is the code for the activity which i m opening from my main activity

```
public class Tnpcell extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tnpcell);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    addShowHideListener(R.id.btn1,fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentplace1));
    addShowHideListener(R.id.btn2,fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentplace2));
    addShowHideListener(R.id.btn3,fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentplace3));
    button4 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          String 
fbPageUrl="https://www.facebook.com/trainingandplacementcell.UIETKUK/";

            try {
                getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana",0);
                Intent fb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("fb://page/1490772567815224" ));
                startActivity(fb);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Intent fb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse(fbPageUrl));
                startActivity(fb);
            }

        }
    });
    Button btntnp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btntnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent a = new Intent(Tnpcell.this, TnpBacktrack.class);
            startActivity(a);
        }
    });
}
void addShowHideListener(int buttonId, final Fragment fragment) {
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(buttonId);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                    android.R.animator.fade_out);
            if (fragment.isHidden()) {
                ft.show(fragment);
                //button1.setText("Hide");
            } else {
                ft.hide(fragment);
                //button1.setText("Show");
            }
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
}
}
```

There is no error in this code .
The code for corresponding xml file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/content_tnp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.dsc.uiet.Tnpcell">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200.0sp"
            android:src="@drawable/uietphoto"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/img1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_remove_white_24dp"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:text="Why Uiet Kuk"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentplace1"
            android:name="com.dsc.uiet.Fragment3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_remove_white_24dp"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:text="Training and Placement Cell"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentplace1"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentplace2"
            android:name="com.dsc.uiet.Fragment2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn2"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_remove_white_24dp"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:text="Contact Us"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentplace2"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentplace3"
            android:name="com.dsc.uiet.Fragment1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn3"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_remove_white_24dp"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:text="Follow Us"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentplace3"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_remove_white_24dp"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:text="Placement Backtrack"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml file for one such fragment is here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tpo" android:background="@color/verylightgray"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView>
...../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The corresponding fragment class has no such special code.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
}
}
```

My Problem is that when i open this activity from the main activity each fragment is shown automatically but i want that each fragment is shown only when the user clicked the button and also the fragment should be shown below the button.
I m new to android and stackoverflow Sorry for silly mistakes or any ignorance.

Comment: u should prefer adding fragments dynamically.

Comment: ya... but i want to find whats the error in my code why the fragments are shown on the opening@Sush

Comment: Your adding fragments statically, so they will visible always . Add them dynamically

Comment: fragments r visible only on the starting.. when i clicked button then fragments get hidden when again clicked they get shown everything is fine ...just they r showing on the start i want to hide them....the whole code is ready so there must be a way  to do that.....see the  whole pocess going on ...chck code... @sush